# isMemberOfClass as a way to manage object

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an NSArray contains `(id)` 6 kind of UIModels: buttons, images and so on..

They all is subclassing of my base model. For example:

```
MyButtonModel : MyUIModel : NSObject
```

So i want to thread it differently in my View.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < [_screenModel.MUIElements count] ; i++)
{
    id UIElement = [_screenModel.MUIElements objectAtIndex:i];
    [self checkWhatKindOfUIElement:UIElement];

}

-(void)checkWhatKindOfUIElement:(id)MUIElement;
{
    if([MUIElement isMemberOfClass:[ButtonModel class]])
        NSLog(@"button");
}
```

So of course i able to get it that way, but do i have to check it 6 ifs ? There is no other way?

Comment: Yes, you have to check it using 6 ifs...

Comment: Is the protocol acceptable to be added to this objects ?

Comment: You're question is unclear.  If you want to know if an object is derived from some common class then `isKindOfClass` will do it for you.  If you want to do six different things for six different classes (and you can't simply do the "different things" in a commonly-named method) then obviously you need six `if` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to check each derived class using *6 ifs*, however I don't think you are using the power of the inheritance model you have already established.  Why not just use the object in whatever way you'd like, perhaps adding methods to expose capabilities; for example:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < [_screenModel.MUIElements count] ; i++)
{
    MyUIModel *UIElement = [_screenModel.MUIElements objectAtIndex:i];

    [UIElement doThingWithString:@"string"];

    if ([UIElement respondsToSelector:@selector(optionalMethod:)])
    {
        [UIElement optionalMethod:12];
    }

    if ([UIElement isCapableOfAnything])
    {
        [UIElement doAnything];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work for derived classes:

```
-(void)checkWhatKindOfUIElement:(id)MUIElement;
{
    if([MUIElement isKindOfClass:[MyUIModel class]])
        NSLog(@"MyUIModel or derived");
}
```

Comment: Nobody says that doesn't work, the question is of optimizing the iteration.